Key Listener in Java Swing
I have a problem. I made a small GUI in Swing that should be a calculator.
I want that if the user type in textfield A  a number and into Textfield B another one there should be a listener that if the user type an operator (+ or - or / or *) it should do the operation with  both numbers. Now I have a problem, the operator will get shown in the textfield which it shoudn't. Any solutions? How can I fix it?
Code is below:
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Taschenrechner extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textB;
    private JTextField textA;
    private JTextField textErgebnis;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Taschenrechner frame = new Taschenrechner();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Taschenrechner() {
        setTitle("Taschenrechner");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        textB = new JTextField();
        textB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loeschenString(textB);
            }
        });
        textB.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent a) {
                if (a.getKeyChar() == '+') {
                    addieren();
                    a.consume(); // Prevent the symbol from appearing in the text field
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '-') {
                    subtrahieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '*') {
                    multiplizieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '/') {
                    dividieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textB.setText("0");
        textB.setBounds(233, 40, 179, 20);
        contentPane.add(textB);
        textB.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblZahlA = new JLabel("Zahl A");
        lblZahlA.setBounds(93, 15, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblZahlA);

        JLabel lblZahlB = new JLabel("Zahl B");
        lblZahlB.setBounds(291, 15, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblZahlB);

        JButton btnSubtstraktion = new JButton("A - B");
        btnSubtstraktion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                subtrahieren();
            }
        });
        btnSubtstraktion.setBounds(233, 94, 179, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSubtstraktion);

        textA = new JTextField();
        textA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loeschenString(textA);
            }
        });
        textA.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent a) {
                if (a.getKeyChar() == '+') {
                    addieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '-') {
                    subtrahieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '*') {
                    multiplizieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
                else if (a.getKeyChar() == '/') {
                    dividieren();
                    a.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textA.setText("0");
        textA.setColumns(10);
        textA.setBounds(20, 40, 179, 20);
        contentPane.add(textA);

        JButton btnAddition = new JButton("A + B");
        btnAddition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addieren();
            }
        });
        btnAddition.setBounds(20, 94, 179, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAddition);

        JButton btnMultiplikation = new JButton("A * B");
        btnMultiplikation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                multiplizieren();
            }
        });
        btnMultiplikation.setBounds(20, 159, 179, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnMultiplikation);

        JButton btnDivision = new JButton("A / B");
        btnDivision.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dividieren();
            }
        });
        btnDivision.setBounds(233, 159, 179, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnDivision);

        JLabel lblErgebnis = new JLabel("Ergebnis");
        lblErgebnis.setBounds(171, 270, 71, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblErgebnis);

        textErgebnis = new JTextField();
        textErgebnis.setEditable(false);
        textErgebnis.setColumns(10);
        textErgebnis.setBounds(122, 310, 179, 20);
        contentPane.add(textErgebnis);
    }

    private void addieren() {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(textA.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(textB.getText());
        int addieren = a + b;
        textErgebnis.setText("" + addieren);
    };

    private void subtrahieren() {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(textA.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(textB.getText());
        int Subtrahieren = a - b;
        textErgebnis.setText("" + Subtrahieren);
    };

    private void multiplizieren() {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(textA.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(textB.getText());
        int Multiplizieren = a * b;
        textErgebnis.setText("" + Multiplizieren);
    };

    private void dividieren() {
        double a = Double.parseDouble(textA.getText());
        double b = Double.parseDouble(textB.getText());
        double Dividieren = a / b;
        textErgebnis.setText("" + Dividieren);
    };

    private void loeschenString(JTextField textField) {
        String eingabe = textField.getText();
        if (eingabe.endsWith("+") || eingabe.endsWith("-") || eingabe.endsWith("*")
                || eingabe.endsWith("/")) {
            textField.setText(eingabe.substring(0, eingabe.length() - 1));
        }
    }
}


This question is similar to: How to allow introducing only digits in jTextField?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"how i can fix it ?"  The same way everyone fixes code.  Run tests and isolate the problem.  Using methods and Swing layout managers would help greatly with isolating the problem.

Use a DocumentListener rather than a KeyListener on the Document underlying the JTextFields.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

In short, the answer to your problem, i.e. not display the operator character, for example + (addition), in the JTextField, is to use a document filter.
Here is a rewrite of your code. My intention is to make you familiar with aspects of Swing that it seems (to me, at least) you are unfamiliar with.
It is recommended to not use a null layout. The below code uses layout managers. It is also recommended to use key bindings rather than key listeners.
The below code also uses switch expressions and method references.
Note that the below code is not production ready. It only handles integer numbers. It doesn't handle integer overflow (or underflow). It performs integer division, meaning that, for example, 5 / 2 will give 2 as the result. But, as stated earlier, my intention is to introduce aspects of Swing which I hope will allow you to develop a production-ready "calculator".
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Calculator extends DocumentFilter implements Runnable {
    private static final String  ADD = "ADD";
    private static final String  DIVIDE = "DIVIDE";
    private static final String  MULTIPLY = "MULTIPLY";
    private static final String  SUBTRACT = "SUBTRACT";

    private JTextField  firstNumberTextField;
    private JTextField  resultTextField;
    private JTextField  secondNumberTextField;

    @Override // javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                        int offset,
                        int length,
                        String text,
                        AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (!"+".equals(text)  &&
            !"-".equals(text)  &&
            !"*".equals(text)  &&
            !"/".equals(text)) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(text);
                fb.replace(offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void add() {
        int firstNumber = getNumber(firstNumberTextField);
        int secondNumber = getNumber(secondNumberTextField);
        int result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JRootPane rootPane = frame.getRootPane();
        setKeyBindings(rootPane, JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        frame.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createResult(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        form.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.right = 30;
        JLabel firstNumberLabel = new JLabel("Number A", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        form.add(firstNumberLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.right = 0;
        JLabel secondNumberLabel = new JLabel("Number B", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        form.add(secondNumberLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets.right = 30;
        gbc.insets.top = 10;
        firstNumberTextField = new JTextField(18);
        AbstractDocument absDocA = (AbstractDocument) firstNumberTextField.getDocument();
        absDocA.setDocumentFilter(this);
        setKeyBindings(firstNumberTextField, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        form.add(firstNumberTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.right = 0;
        secondNumberTextField = new JTextField(18);
        AbstractDocument absDocB = (AbstractDocument) secondNumberTextField.getDocument();
        absDocB.setDocumentFilter(this);
        setKeyBindings(secondNumberTextField, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        form.add(secondNumberTextField, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.insets.right = 30;
        gbc.insets.top = 30;
        JButton addButton = new JButton("A + B");
        addButton.setActionCommand(ADD);
        addButton.addActionListener(this::performOperation);
        form.add(addButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.right = 0;
        JButton subtractButton = new JButton("A - B");
        subtractButton.setActionCommand(SUBTRACT);
        subtractButton.addActionListener(this::performOperation);
        form.add(subtractButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets.right = 30;
        JButton multiplyButton = new JButton("A * B");
        multiplyButton.setActionCommand(MULTIPLY);
        multiplyButton.addActionListener(this::performOperation);
        form.add(multiplyButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.right = 0;
        JButton divideButton = new JButton("A / B");
        divideButton.setActionCommand(DIVIDE);
        divideButton.addActionListener(this::performOperation);
        form.add(divideButton, gbc);
        return form;
    }

    private JPanel createResult() {
        JPanel result = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10));
        result.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40, 0, 20, 0));
        JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        result.add(resultLabel);
        resultTextField = new JTextField(18);
        resultTextField.setEditable(false);
        resultTextField.setFocusable(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(resultTextField);
        result.add(panel);
        return result;
    }

    private void divide() {
        int firstNumber = getNumber(firstNumberTextField);
        int secondNumber = getNumber(secondNumberTextField);
        int result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }

    private int getNumber(JTextField textField) {
        String numberText = textField.getText();
        int number;
        if (numberText.isEmpty()) {
            number = 0;
        }
        else {
            number = Integer.parseInt(numberText);
        }
        return number;
    }

    private void multiply() {
        int firstNumber = getNumber(firstNumberTextField);
        int secondNumber = getNumber(secondNumberTextField);
        int result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }

    private void performOperation(ActionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionCommand()) {
            case ADD -> add();
            case DIVIDE -> divide();
            case MULTIPLY -> multiply();
            case SUBTRACT -> subtract();
            default -> System.out.println("What the...?");
        }
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(JComponent jCmpt, int type) {
        InputMap im = jCmpt.getInputMap(type);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('+'), ADD);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('/'), DIVIDE);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('*'), MULTIPLY);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('-'), SUBTRACT);
        ActionMap am = jCmpt.getActionMap();
        am.put(ADD, new AddAction());
        am.put(DIVIDE, new DivideAction());
        am.put(MULTIPLY, new MultiplyAction());
        am.put(SUBTRACT, new SubtractAction());
    }

    private void subtract() {
        int firstNumber = getNumber(firstNumberTextField);
        int secondNumber = getNumber(secondNumberTextField);
        int result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }

    private class AddAction extends AbstractAction {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            add();
        }
    }

    private class DivideAction extends AbstractAction {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            divide();
        }
    }

    private class MultiplyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            multiply();
        }
    }

    private class SubtractAction extends AbstractAction {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            subtract();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Calculator());
    }
}

I did not discover why, but setting key bindings for the root pane did not apply to the JTextFields – but it did for all the JButtons. Hence I also explicitly set key bindings for the JTextFields.
Here is a screen capture:

